# Crash in tableView with CABasicAnimation, textColor when the TableViewCell is not visible

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uitableview

The application is a satisfaction survey that all the fields must be filled by people. I used a tableView and I would like, when a field is not filled, that it scrolls automatically to the field, that it put the tableviewcell in red, and that it shake the tableviewcell. I found all that but the problem is that it seems that it crash when the cell is not on the screen (may be because of the fact that the cell is not visible on the screen).

May be I have to do something to wait for the cell is visible first. How can I do that ?

```
    let cellPb = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0))

    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
    //color
    cellPb!.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //shake the cell
    let shake = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    shake.duration = 0.1
    shake.repeatCount = 3
    shake.autoreverses = true
    shake.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(cellPb!.center.x - 5, cellPb!.center.y))
    shake.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(cellPb!.center.x + 5, cellPb!.center.y))
    cellPb!.layer.addAnimation(shake, forKey: "position")

 UIAlertView(title: "Please, fill the blank field.", message: nil, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()
```

Comment: I would suggest first check whether cell is in VisibleCells or not. If not in Visible cells then divide the task into two queue i.e. main. In first  the scroll to visible cells & in second create the animation.

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other way round, **first scroll** then get the cell:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)    
let cellPb = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Comment: Perfect and simple :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cellPb!.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Above line forcefully unwrap the value. that's why it will crash. so use 
**if let** this is safe way to unwrap any value

Try this code

```
       if let cellPb = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)) {
            //color
            cellPb.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

            //shake the cell
            let shake = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            shake.duration = 0.1
            shake.repeatCount = 3
            shake.autoreverses = true
            shake.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(cellPb!.center.x - 5, cellPb!.center.y))
            shake.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(cellPb!.center.x + 5, cellPb!.center.y))
            cellPb.layer.addAnimation(shake, forKey: "position")

            UIAlertView(title: "Please, fill the blank field.", message: nil, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()
        } else {
             self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: false)
        }
```